# Remove Shipping Block in New Order Email

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipping, sales-order, order-email

I want to remove the line "Shipping & Handling $0.00" from "new order" emails. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: please  add  more detail and provide your work

Comment: Hello @GopalPatel I am adding ss in question.want to remove shipping&handling line

Answer (score 1):

you need to delete this code!

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php

```
     /**
     * Add shipping

    if (!$source->getIsVirtual() && ((float) $source->getShippingAmount() || $source->getShippingDescription()))
    {
        $this->_totals['shipping'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'  => 'shipping',
            'field' => 'shipping_amount',
            'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
            'label' => $this->__('Shipping & Handling')
        ));
    }
    */
```

It works!

Comment: It will remove `Shipping & Handling` from all feature like cart page , invoice  , order and all

Comment: No. you can see `Shipping & Handling` label on the checkout page and order page on backend page even though i delete this code! Check it out

Comment: it is not working @3CE